# Call Same Function with Diffent Parameters

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.3.6

I am using 1.9.3.6. In `Namespace_MOdule_Model_Catalog_Layer`, calling the Same function with different Parameters as below at the same time.

```
 public function attributeCollection($colln = "", $query = "",$type = "")
{

    $labelArray = $valueArray = $resultArray = array();

    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attribute = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($type);
    $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
        if ($attributeOption["label"] != "") {
            array_push($labelArray, $attributeOption["label"]);
            array_push($valueArray, $attributeOption["value"]);
        }
    }
    $combinedArray = array_combine($valueArray, $labelArray);

    foreach ($combinedArray as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($value, $query)) {
            array_push($resultArray, $key);
        }
    }

    $colln->addAttributeToFilter($type, array('in' => $resultArray ));

    return $colln->getData();
}



        $brandCollection = $this->attributeCollection($collection, $query, $type="brand");
        $modelCollection = $this->attributeCollection($collection, $query, $type="model");

        echo "<pre>";

        print_r($brandCollection);
        print_r($modelCollection);
```

If the `$query` is in `$brandCollection` then it is prints fine.
Otherwise, if the `$query` is in `$modelCollection` it is empty.

How to fix it.

Comment: It means that you don't have any data with 'model` attribute

Comment: @KeyurShah Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Fixed this using Following Solution.

```
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=> 'brand','finset' => $brandCollection),array('attribute'=> 'model','finset' => $modelCollection) ));
```

My Final Code is:

```
$brandArray = $this->attributeCollection($collection, $query, $type="brand");
$modelArray = $this->attributeCollection($collection, $query, $type="model");
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=> 'brand','finset' => $brandArray),array('attribute'=> 'model','finset' => $modelArray) ));



public function attributeCollection($colln = "", $query = "",$type = "")
  { 
    $labelArray = $valueArray = $resultArray = array();
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attribute = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($type);
    $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
        if ($attributeOption["label"] != "") {
            array_push($labelArray, $attributeOption["label"]);
            array_push($valueArray, $attributeOption["value"]);
        }
    }
    $combinedArray = array_combine($valueArray, $labelArray);

    foreach ($combinedArray as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($value, $query)) {
            array_push($resultArray, $key);
        }
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```